# AngularJS animating prepended $scope data

Tags: angularjs, animation, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have an array named $scope.data with some objects in it, and then I make a call and get older data and I prepend the data to the array.

```
  TestQuery.query({start:0, end: Date.now()}, function(response){

    if (response.length > 0) {
      response.reverse();
      $scope.data.reverse();
      $scope.data = $scope.data.concat(response).reverse();
    };


  });
```

How would you go about animating this change in scope? I want to move the text down and animate the new data coming in. Simple is fine and preferable. Very new to Angular, help is very much appreciated. I would like to remain in Angular world and not use any jQuery is possible.

Comment: Sorry if this is a little general, I just need an example of Angular animations and I can hold my own.

Comment: Currently, I am using the animate.css library and adding a class that bounces the prepended data. Because ng-repeat makes those divs new, it animates the prepended data but I was wondering how to do this with ng-class and directives.